# How to create a search box and SQL statement for searching an attribute field?

Tags: sql, html, carto

How can I add a HTML search bar that the user can use to search an attribute field for a polygon layer, and then tie that input into the SQL statement?

So far I am able to hard code the query  of sending a SQL statement and returning a answer using cartodb. My problem is figuring out how to  take the input from the search box and automatically inserting the input into the sql statement.

I am using Cartodb api.

```
 var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'jmann111' });
   sql.getBounds("select * from stations where station_nm like ='%" + user_input +"'").done(function(bounds) {
  map.fitBounds(bounds)
  });
```

Comment: for connecting to SQL you should do this on the server not the client - using php can do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795791/how-to-perform-sql-command-on-html-page-with-user-input-field-and-show-result-o

Comment: my user input is `'; drop table stations; --`. I hope you have a backup...what i mean is you are opening yourself to a huge SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: See also for ways to securely CartoDB https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134156/avoiding-sql-injection-when-updating-tables-through-cartodb-api/169213#169213

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you will need a parameter, usually declared somewhere before the select statement. The parameter is the same as a variable. So something like:
Declare @userinput as varchar
Set @userinput = textbox.text
Select * From stations where Station_nm Like '%@userinput%'

Your command has like = and they can't be used together.

Comment: Thank you User20498 this is what i was looking for how ever still having problems implementing  this practice  even just setting the parameter to a default value I am getting a syntax error for in my Declare parameter @

Comment: to CrazySpatial , command should be Like '%' + @userinput instead of = . But that looks like it is vulnerable to sql injection. I strongly recommend that you read about it